# GTK+ in Kubuntu apps look bad

Tags: kde, gtk, qt, evolution, plasma

I have installed Evolution email client on Kubuntu 11.10 and it's not so cute as expected.

[image]

Eclipse also looks bad. I have the GTK+ Appearance plugin in KDE System Settings and already tried QTCurve and Oxygen option, no help. When the GTK+ skin was working, this appearance still showed when I ran an application as root.

Tried:

```
sudo apt-get install oxygen-molecule gtk2-engines-oxygen
```

There is a problem with KDE/GTK relation. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accidentally found the right answer [here](http://www.netrunner-os.com/gtk2-gtk3-configuration-under-kde/)

---

### UPDATE

Old question with old answers, but maybe still interesting - and appearing in internet searches anyway. So, for the record:

In KDE/Plasma5, there are GTK settings in the System Settings, Application Style:

[image]

Comment: [It is preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you have the following packages installed (they should have been installed by kubuntu-desktop, but may have gotten missed):

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-oxygen kde-config-gtk
```

Then go to the KDE Control centre and make sure that the checkbox for using KDE themes in GTK apps is checked.

Answer (score 3):

Evolution probably uses GTK3 while the instructions are valid only for GTK2.

I'm not sure what is the policy of AskUbuntu on external links, but this one provides a solution for GTK3:

http://maketecheasier.com/make-gtk3-apps-look-presentable-in-kde4/2012/01/04

Comment: [It is preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Fixed it for me! Fwiw, the command is `sudo apt-get install gtk3-engines-oxygen`.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.netrunner-os.com/gtk2-gtk3-configuration-under-kde/) is the latest gtk config tool that allows easy customization of GTK2 + GTK3 under KDE

It will likely become official tool in next KDE version.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but a work around. Try setting your appearance with lxappearance

```
sudo apt-get install lxappearance
```

It (lxappearance) should be in your KDE menu, under settings, or run it manually with `lxappearance`.

lxappearance seems to work better then `kde-config-gtk` for some people

Another potential problem is running applications as root.

```
sudo cp /root/.gtkrc-2.0 /root/.gtkrc-2.0.backup
sudo cp /root/.gtkrc-2.0-kde4 /root/.gtkrc-2.0
```

You can un-do that command if needed (you might break gksu or running applications as root under gnome or other DE, may not be an issue if you only run KDE)

Comment: Eclipse is fixed now, but Evolution not.

Comment: One out of 2 is not bad =) , sorry you are having problems.

Answer (score 0):

KDE uses the "system" font hinting as default (where is this system hinting config located?), and GTK not.

So, make KDE uses the QT configuration, which will force GTK to use the same.

On KDE Settings, Application Appearence, Fonts, I selected "Use anti-aliasing" as "Enabled", opened "Configure", than unchecked "exclude range", checked "use subpixel", and select "slight" for "hinting style". This will force gtk to use the same font hinting.

Answer (score -1):

get the package for your distribution here:

https://community.kde.org/Plasma/Packages

systemsettings > appearance > application style (or smth like that> gnome gtk menu entry