# gtk applications in kubuntu 11.10

Tags: kubuntu, kde, gtk

I check

[GTK+ in Kubuntu apps look bad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87037/gtk-in-kubuntu-apps-look-bad)

and configure all by recommendations

[image]

[image]

but oxygen-gtk theme does not affect the appearance

Comment: Do what you've done but with a GTK3 theme that why nautilus looks like that.

Answer (score 2):

I have posted a complement to the question you linked to.

This application on the first screenshot is probably using GTK3, while the original instructions only apply to GTK2. I posted over there a link to a site that gives instructions for fixing GTK3. I'm not posting here too because I'm not sure if this would be considered duplication.

Comment: I followed the instructions. But I have some problems when I launch nautilus. htop show 98% cpu load  but nautilus window doesn't appear

Answer (score 2):

Now that you have gtk3-engines-oxygen installed you need to do another step; inside ~/.config/ create a new directory with **gtk-3.0** as it's name, then inside that directory create a new file, name it **settings.ini**  inside that file put this:

```
 [Settings]
gtk-theme-name = oxygen-gtk
```

Save and close, then you must be able to see gtk applications very well integrated with oxygen theme. If not, open **systemsettings** again, go to  GTK appearance and reselect the oxyge-gtk theme, save settings. Now you should be able to see good looking GTK applications.

This worked for me as far I compiled the oxygen-gtk theme from it's lastest tarball, maybe you won't need that but if the latter isn't working for you, you should consider compiling.

Hope this helps! Good Luck!