# GTK apps not respecting Kubuntu's oxygen-gtk theme when executed as sudo

Tags: kubuntu, themes, sudo, gtk, gksudo

I am using Kubuntu 14.10 and it's working quite well so far, but my problem is pretty much what it's stated in the title, when executing a GTK app that requires sudo privileges, such as Synaptic package manager, it's displayed with an ugly theme and huge fonts. However if starting the app without sudo, oxygen-gtk theme is respected. Sometimes the app won't even run until next reboot, displaying a message in terminal about not being able to open display X.

I've tried every possible theme in "System configuration -> Application appearance -> GTK" and other fixes suggested on forums around the web and even [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87037/gtk-in-kubuntu-apps-look-bad) in askubuntu but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Preserving GTK theme with gksudo](/q/517539)

Answer (score 0):

Run the command below and re-apply the oxygen-gtk theme:

```
kdesudo systemsettings
```

Comment: By the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo : "You should never use normal sudo to start graphical applications as Root. You should use gksudo (kdesudo on Kubuntu) to run such programs..."

Answer (score 0):

Copy everything `gtk-3.0` and `.gtkrc-20` from `~`, `~/.config`, `~/.kde/share/config` to `/root`.

That's how my `synaptic` renders Kubuntu's Oxygen-GTK theme.

Comment: welcome to Ask Ubuntu it is highly unrecommended to copy anything to your root folder

Comment: The was no recommendation to do anything. .There simply was an answer to a question which presented a problem. You did not address the question or the problem, but saw fit to downgrade the answer. That does not seem productive.

Comment: other than setting gtk rc files adding `Defaults    env_keep += "DESKTOP_SESSION" # keep colors` to /etc/sudoers may help